# Auto Refresh a page in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie in Ruby On Rails, Can someone tell me how to refresh a page.

1. Without any values submitted
2. With previous values submitted

Comment: When you say "refresh" do you mean the page will automatically refresh itself every "n" minutes, or is there a control (e.g., button) that the user will activate to refresh the page?

Comment: it will automatically refresh

Answer (score 7):

[ActionView::Helpers::PrototypeHelper#periodically_call_remote](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M002168):

1. Without any values submitted

   ```
   <%= periodically_call_remote(:url => {}) %>
   ```
2. With previous values resubmitted:

   ```
   <%= periodically_call_remote(:url => params) %>
   ```

You can provide a :frequency option to specify how often to call it.

You may also want to set up the format.js block in the controller to render an RJS template that will only update things that could change.

**Edit: This approach was deprecated with version Rails 3.0**

This question ([Rails 3 equivalent for periodically_call_remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661967/rails-3-equivalent-for-periodically-call-remote)) provides a method for accomplishing this in newer versions of Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Your link seems to be broken.

Comment: Not broken, just deprecated. I've updated the link to point to the documentation of the last version of rails this was supported, I've also added a link to answer that provides an method of accomplishing this in newer versions of Rails.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the below script to auto refresh a full page...

setTimeout("location.reload();",10000);

Comment: script language="javascript" type="text/javascript