# Rails: periodically_call_remote then redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

I need to check some database values with a `periodically_call_remote` function.
I want to redirect if some values have already a certain state.

How to do this? `redirect_to` in the function does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to do a refresh on the entire page?  You could use javascript to update your content.

The following javascript may work as well.

```
window.location = "http://www.address.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

redirect_to in the return function does not work because it redirects the ajax request to the new page, it doesn't tell the browser to redirect the entire page. You will need to either render back some javascript in the controller that causes the page to redirect, or better: add a callback to the periodically_call_remote call that checks the return value and runs the javascript that Ben suggested.

Comment: that was then also my conclusion, thanks, I got it solved now

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread:

[Rails 3 equivalent for periodically_call_remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661967/rails-3-equivalent-for-periodically-call-remote)

The first answer to use javascript setInterval worked perfectly.