# calling and dynamically updating jquery functions

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement jquery replacement for the old periodically_call_remote.  I got the following code from another stackoverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661967/rails-3-equivalent-for-periodically-call-remote):

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    setInterval(function(){
      $('#mydiv').load('/controller/action');
    }, 3000);
  });
```

But I am struggling to make it work.  If I understand UJS correctly, if I do the following things:

- Place the script in application.js
- include application.js in my layout (which javascript_include_tag :defaults does)
- have a DOM element in my view template with id='mydiv'

Then the function should automatically bind to 'mydiv' and execute after the page is loaded, right?  Is there a step I am missing?  I should not have to name the function or call it directly in the view, correct?

Second, how can I dynamically update the load URL.  For instance, I have a nested resource with the path '/controller/:id/action' ... how do I dynamically insert the :id value into the load path at render time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this unobtrusively is to set an attribute in the div tag that you want to load and then grab it from within the application.js file.

some.html

```
<div data-delay-load="<%= url_for() %>"></div>
```

application.js

```
$(function() {

    $('div[data-delay-load]').each( function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('data-delay-load'),
            $element = $(this);

        var _func = function() {
           $element.load(url);
        }

        setTimeout(_func, 3000);
    });
});
```

What is nice is that you can have a delay load on any page or multiple elements on the same page just by including the data-delay-load attribute.

Comment: Thanks.  After I posted, I realized I didn't need the :id, so I changed my routes declaration so the action was on the collection rather than a member.  That allows me to use a simple string for my load url, eg .load('action/controller').  However, for some reason the resulting http request appends the string to the full current url rather than the base url, eg GET base/controller/action/controller/action.  Any idea why?

Comment: disregard my question, was a simple syntax error, needed slash in front of the path, eg .load('/controller/action')

Answer (score 1):

Add the following inside you functions.

```
$('#mydiv').css("background", "red");
```

Did the color of the div change? If it did, debug your server side code.

If you know how to open a JavaScript console in your browser, open it and see if there are any errors.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't answer the question but helped me find out what the problem was.